# How do I properly hide a container view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicontainerview

I have a container view on top of my view controller and when I use this code to try and hide the container view, the container view disappears BUT the view controller underneath becomes user disabled. As in you cant touch anything or do anything.

This is the code I am using:

```
[self.childViewControllers[0] view].hidden = YES;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drag the outlet of your containerView and hide it.

```
yourContainerView.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: Yup, that did it. :) Thank you. Much appreciated!